# What to use to upload different file formats(audio,video) in Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload

Does carrier wave support file format like .doc ,.pdf and other paper file formats?If not what is out there to use?
what could i use to enable user to upload audio and video in ruby on rails application?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can upload files of any kind using CarrierWave. For some formats it has built in features that let you post process the uploaded files, for some formats it doesn't. But you can use it with files of any kind. See [here](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave) for more information.